# how to keep default click effect when I change button background in Android?

Tags: android, android-button

when I use **default background** on button, I click button, the button's background will be dark gray.

But when I **change button background** (custom image) , the default click effect(dark gray) is disappeared.

how to keep default click effect when I change button background in android?

Comment: What is a click effect? Can I guess you mean the change of minor/temporary change of colour when a user tap a button?

Comment: when you click button, the button background color will be darker, this is click effect.

Comment: You mean a selector got you check the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this attribute

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well then you can call it a **Selector** and not Click Effect. What happens is that you make a file in drawable folder with alternative background colors or images to different states of the `Button`. A selector file can be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_when_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_when_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

So you can put images or colors but at the end you will have to set the whole file as your background to a `Button` like:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button"
 android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="126dp"/>
```

So the default button clicks had a default selector, if you change the background also change the selector using images or colours.

Comment: I don't want to set `selector` for button . it is very inconvenient and Cumbersome, because i need set `selector` for every button. I only want keep button **default click effect**. I want change button default `style`, but i don't know how to do?

Comment: Which effect do you mean? is it ripple effect or something?

Comment: only make backgroud be darker gray.  sorry, my english is very poor, i don't konw how to express more clearly.

Comment: Why dont you use a selector and put colors instead of images?

Comment: i set images to be background, i want click this button, the images will be dark(like cover a semitransparent gray color on image). if using selector, i will process every image twice(light images and dark images), and I need set `selector` for every button.

Comment: Put each of your button in its own linear layout linear layout, then apply the background to the linear layout, then the background of your button to be a simple selector to change the transparency for all button it will look darker depeding on how you have set it